# Вводные слова в скобках

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Нужна ли запятая в скобках? По правилам вводное слово отделяется, но тут все почему-то воспринимается как единое целое...

Опытный руководитель понимает, что если что-то делает не так, как надо, это всегда потом обнаруживается (может быть и не сразу) и иногда может принести неприятности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опытный руководитель понимает, что если что-то делает не так, как надо, это всегда потом обнаруживается (может быть, и не сразу) и иногда может принести неприятности.

Если внутри вставной конструкции находится вводное слово, то вводное слово выделяется запятыми, а вводная конструкция с помощью тире или скобок:

Письмо было написано мелким почерком (очень, кстати, неразборчивым). 
Враги его, друзья его (что, может быть, одно и то же) его честили так и сяк.

**Сравнить:** "Так вот, Роман Самгин, может быть и не сразу, но обнаружил ярко выраженную генетическую склонность или, проще говоря, режиссерский талант, а интенсивную работоспособность почувствовал или приобрел сразу".  Здесь вводное слово входит в состав обособленного оборота и не обосособляетя.

**Из Правил Лопатина:** В тексте вставной конструкции сохраняются все необходимые для нее знаки (запятая, восклицательный и вопросительный знаки, многоточие, двоеточие).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Меня тут просто присоединительный союз "и" смутил...

Answer (score 0):

Я бы поставил. Понимаете, вводные слова в начале подчиненного предложения или обособленного оборота и только к нему относящиеся обычно не отделаются от этого оборота по мотивам наглядности, иначе запятые путаются, не видны границы вставной конструкции.

Но тут-то проблем с восприятием быть не может.
Где-то на другом профильном ресурсе я видел дискуссию на эту тему, и там в целом согласись с таким подходом.  Других источников не знаю.