# "Плюш" и "плис"

Tags: этимология, терминология

Не знаю, уместен ли здесь этот вопрос. Если нет, скажите — и я удалю его.

Меня интересует, *есть ли разница между **плюшем** и **плисом**, или это одна и та же ткань.*

Comment: Тём, но основы-то две: *разница есть* и *это ткань*. Щас схожу за правилом.

Comment: Союзы *ли…или* в сложносочиненном предложении относятся к повторяющимся союзам. Это же сочетание союзов может использоваться и в предложении со сказуемыми, отнесенными к общему подлежащему, тогда запятая перед или не ставится. Ср.: ***Судьба ли нас свела опять на Кавказе, или она нарочно сюда приехала, зная, что меня встретит*** (Л.). – ***Видит ли он это или не видит – не столь важно***.

Comment: https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/

Comment: **ЛИ/ЛЬ... ИЛИ, *союз***: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_392

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova: интересно, не знал! Спасибо большое! Интуиция ошибочно подсказывала, что запятая в таком случае не нужна, даже сомнений не было, поэтому не проверял.

Comment: Тёмыч, а я не стала размахивать руками, потому что у нас СПП, плавно перетекающее в ССП. Я ж правил не знаю, говорила тебе. Даже как всё вот етое называется - ну низнайу. Я плохо училась; практик мы.

Comment: Я тоже терминологии мало знаю и правил.

Comment: http://kuvaldinur.narod.ru/kuvaldin-ru/persony/eremenko-aleksandr.html и https://litresp.ru/chitat/ru/%D0%95/eremeno-aleksandr/gorizontaljnaya-strana-stihotvoreniya/93

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следующие ссылки на [плюш](https://textiletrend.ru/pro-tkani/naturalnyie/plyush.html) и [плис](https://textiletrend.ru/pro-tkani/naturalnyie/plis.html) выглядят на первый взгляд достаточно грамотно и не противоречат информации в других источниках (в Википедии, например), но при этом более подробны.

По этим ссылкам плис является более простым и дешёвым аналогом плюша. Основное отличие в технологии изготовления — материал ворсовой нити: у плиса ворсовые нити почти всегда хлопчатобумажные, а ворс у плюша делают из шерсти или шёлка.

Comment: Спасибо, гризли! Надеюсь, можно этому верить. :)

Comment: @Артём Луговой  Уточнение по поводу правки. Если оборот с вводным словом стоит в скобках, то вводное отделяется запятой:  http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2 (примечание 1).

Comment: @Александр: какие-то примеры неубедительные... :(

Comment: Вот здесь подробнее расписано: https://popravilam.com/blog/071-zapyatye-posle-naprimer.html

Comment: Ответ Sharon: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423029/Вводные-слова-в-скобках